# HTML/CSS not able to be a sticky element?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an image that is a sticky element. However, when I try to make it work, it simply doesn't follow those rules. The sticky property works for every other element on the page, so I am not sure what is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML -

```
<HTML>
<head>
    <title> Stunning Web Design </title>
    <link rel = 'stylesheet' type = "text/css" href = "main.css">
    <div id = "fonts">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin" rel="stylesheet">
    </div>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "images">
    <img id = "fall_bridge" src = "Photos/fall_bridge.jpg" alt = "Beautiful Paris Photo" width = 1482 height = 720>
    </div>
    <p id = 'backPlate'> </p>
    <h1 id = "mainTitle"> Stunning Web Design </h1>
</body>
```

My CSS -

```
#fall_bridge {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* safari enabled */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    border: 5px solid white; 
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
     filter: grayscale(100%);

}

#mainTitle {
    border: 8px double white;
    background-color: rgba(148, 149, 153, .8);
    width: 680px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1100px;
    left: 380px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

img {


}

#backPlate {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 1488px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The surrounding div `#images` is affecting it. If you apply the sticky properties to `#images` instead of `#fall_bridge`, it should work (if that is your desired result).

A bit off-topic but I noticed you have your web fonts in your head inside of a div? Any reason for that? Divs shouldn't need to be in your `head` tag.

Comment: I am going to have a lot of fonts by the end, so I need a DIV, or else it's going to get crazy

Comment: I'm not sure how putting them in a DIV will make a difference? Any webfonts listed in your head tag will be pulled in / loaded into the page, wrapping them in a DIV doesn't really change anything. DIVs are typically for page layout in the body. The fonts load in the background for use on the page, not to a position on the page. 

While they may render in some browsers, I don't think it's valid to have a DIV tag in the HEAD tag.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't sticky because of the `<div id="images">` surrounding it. Either make the div sticky or the image. If you are making the image sticky, remove the div.

```css
#fall_bridge {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 5px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

#mainTitle {
  border: 8px double white;
  background-color: rgba(148, 149, 153, .8);
  width: 680px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1100px;
  left: 380px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}


#backPlate {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 1488px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin" rel="stylesheet">
  <img id="fall_bridge" src="https://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large/fall-bridge-hala-eliya.jpg" alt="Beautiful Paris Photo" width="500px">
<p id='backPlate'> </p>
<h1 id="mainTitle"> Stunning Web Design </h1>
```